# Testing whether a variable outside the current module is written to

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I'm trying to write a pytest suite for functions that write to variables in a dedicated global_variables module, and I can't work out how to check if the variables are getting written there. I've tried using pytest-mock's mocker.patch to mock the variables, but mocker seems to just allow you to read in from a mocked variable, not write to one.

The code being tested:

```
import global_variables as gv

def main(filename):
    gv.name = filename
    do_other_stuff()
```

My unit test:

```
import pytest

def test_main_writes_to_gv():
    # arrange
    output = mocker.patch(gv.name)
    # act
    app.main('foo')
    # assert
    assert output == 'foo'
```

I want to add some sort of listener to see if gv.name is being written to, similar to the way that mocker's .assert_called_with() method works, but I'm looking for something like .assert_written_to.

Comment: You might be interested in [`PropertyMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock).